# Display different fields on Promoted Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, promoted-links

I have a very interesting question that I do not even know if it is possible. I am using Promoted Links and I want to display additional fields on the tile.  I tried to use the description field but it is not giving me the outcome.  I do have three fields Target, Actual and Gap that need to be on the tile.

Can you add the additional fields?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that we cannot add additional fields in the Tiles view.

It only can display the Title and Description columns in the Tiles view.

It is by design.

Answer (score 0):

The only words you can put up there are the Title and Description.

To add your other text you could manipulate the css overlay of the tile.  There are some great resources here detailing how to manipulate the css to do a lot of things.